# Robolectric 3.0 not working with AppCompat 21+

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, robolectric, appcompat-v7-toolbar

After upgrading to AppCompat 21, a lot of our Robolectric tests fail. It looks like there is an issue with the Toolbar and AppCompatDelegate

I tried both with support-v4/appcompat 22.2.1 and the versions used in the official sample for appcompat:

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples/tree/master/android-appcompat-v7

```
    Android Studio 1.3 RC4, Android Gradle Plugin 1.2.3

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
```

Test Sample

```
    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
    @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
    public class ActivateAccountActivityTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldRunActivateAccountActivity() throws Exception {
            // Given
            ActivateAccountActivity activateAccountActivity =
                    Robolectric.buildActivity(ActivateAccountActivity.class).create().start().get();

            // Then
            assertNotNull(activateAccountActivity.getFragment(ActivateAccountFragment.class));
        }
    }
```

Tests fail with the following stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/app/debug/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivity.onCreate(ActivateAccountActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivityTest.shouldRunActivateAccountActivity(ActivateAccountActivityTest.java:40)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.$$robo$$ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.$$robo$$setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.$$robo$$setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivity.onCreate(ActivateAccountActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivityTest.shouldRunActivateAccountActivity(ActivateAccountActivityTest.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:173)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.__constructor__(Toolbar.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivity.onCreate(ActivateAccountActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
        at com.foo.myapp.Activities.ActivateAccountActivityTest.shouldRunActivateAccountActivity(ActivateAccountActivityTest.java:40)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: We don't have this issue. We use AppCompat 22.2.0 and Robolectric 3.0. What runner do you use? Can you share example of your test?

Comment: Test Sample added to the question. We use RobolectricGradleTestRunner.  Do you use AppCompatActivity/ActionBarActivity? What is your minSDK?

Comment: We use AppCompatActivity, our minimum sdk is 17. Also we specify `sdk = 21` in `@Config` section of test. I don't know what will be default sdk when you don't specify it. Probably 16 or 18

Comment: Tried with `minSDK 17` and `sdk = 21`, same behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have some custom views?

Comment: No, this activity just has a `FrameLayout`, in which we put a Fragment some time later in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a library that depends on support-4v:19. 
Adding the following to the build file resolved the issue

```
    testCompile('com.example.foo') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got very similar issue and my issue was fixed after I remove 
"testCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8')" 
from my build.gradle.

I found this information from the [Robolectric migration document](http://evendanan.net/robolectric/unit-test/2015/04/09/migrating-to-robolectric-v3/) and extracted below. Hope it helps.

> DO NOT USE com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8. If you have it in your
>   testCompile be sure to remove it. There is a conflict between it and
>   Robolectric which causes all Fragment/Activity related unit-tests to
>   fail with NoSuchMethodError.  If you have to use
>   com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8, then remove support-v4 from it:
>   testCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8') {
>           exclude module: 'support-v4' }